# sql statement if exists update else insert sql server

Tags: sql-server, insert

nice to back again 
i m working on project to calculate measures and numbers and insert data inside datagridview(dgv) from number.text and measure.text but if value of measure.text present in dgv son update number cell with new value + present value 
problem is how to do so....
i tried alot of sql statements but i have errors

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

        If Not sqlcon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            '  open connection
            sqlcon.Open()
        End If
                com2 = New SqlCommand("UPDATE frames SET [number] = [number] + '" & number.Text & "' where measure = '" & measure.Text & "'", sqlcon)
                com2.ExecuteNonQuery()

                com = New SqlCommand("insert into frames ([number],measure) values('" & number.Text & "','" & measure.Text & "'),('" & number1.Text & "','" & measure1.Text & "')", sqlcon)
                com.ExecuteNonQuery()

            End If
        Next


    End Sub
```

this is the code i m working on but i search for better way and find this ones

```
com2 = New SqlCommand("UPDATE frames SET [number] = [number] + '" & number.Text & "' where measure = '" & measure.Text & "' if @@rowcount=0 insert into frames ([number],measure) values('" & number.Text & "','" & measure.Text & "'),('" & number1.Text & "','" & measure1.Text & "'", sqlcon)
com2.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

but it give me error  *Incorrect syntax near '93.5'* .........93.5 is value exists in measure.text but all sql statement ok except this error i dont know why
i have tried another way

```
com = New SqlCommand("IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM  frames) BEGIN insert into frames ([number],measure) values('" & number.Text & "','" & measure.Text & "'),('" & number1.Text & "','" & measure1.Text & "') END ELSE BEGIN UPDATE frames SET [number] = [number] + '" & number.Text & "' where measure = '" & measure.Text & "'", sqlcon)
com2 = New SqlCommand("IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM frames) THEN BEGIN Update frames set [number] = [number] + '" & number.Text & "' where measure = '" & measure.Text & "' End ELSE bEGIN INSERT INTO frames ([number],measure) values('" & number.Text & "','" & measure.Text & "'),('" & number1.Text & "','" & measure1.Text & "' END", sqlcon)
com2.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

i got this error "****Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'THEN'.

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'END'.****" or

i got this error "Incorrect syntax near '61.19'." .........61.19 is value present in measure.text

please help me find way to do that without errors or what wrong in these????

i heared about transaction but i searched this way and understand nothing .....

Comment: We don't use THEN with IF in sql.   Please consult MSDN for correct examples.

Comment: You might try creating the sql syntax in sql server first. Once you have it working there, then copy/paste that sql into your code. SQL Server will point right to your errors.

Comment: In com = you forgot to add `END` at last of string  and in com2=  you have added `THEN` after if exist which is not correct.